# List all branches of a particular repository

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to fetch all branches of one of my repository on git. It returns only 30 branches but it has more than that.

```
curl  -H "Authorization: Bearer Token"  https://api.github.com/repos/account_name/repo_name/branches
```

This curl lists only 30 branches. Is there any way to list all branches?

Answer (score 0):

You can request more results per page using the `per_page` parameter:

https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

There is a limit to how many you can request per page, so you should always be prepared to follow their [pagination guide](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/).